# What is Business rule engine?

Tags: php, rule

I was asked about available business rule engine in PHP. After researching I found that RuleEngine is available which can be used but I am not sure how to use this. Can anyone explain how RuleEngine works

Answer (score 3):

In most projects, we have some business rules which affect on our processes and outputs. It is a best practice to design a rule engine in our project to control all the rules.

The reasons for having a rule engine:

- The rules may be changed many times. So If we have a rule engine, we just need to change one place, not much code in the project.
- We can create many unit test on our rules easily.
- Our codes will be more readable.
- Rule engine will be a new layer which is separated from other layers.

**In php:** I have made a simple method to create a rule engine. You can use that to make one for your project:

[A Simple Method to Make a Rule Engine in PHP](https://github.com/a-afsharfarnia/php-rule-engine)

**Be successful.**

Comment: Your answer looks good and on-topic to me, @abbas, (not that I am an expert on the topic), but you should disclose in the answer text that the link is to your own software. (Nothing wrong with that, as long as you are up front about it.)

Answer (score 1):

In short and simple, a [business rule engine](http://www.flexrule.com/bre), is a component (a middleware) that your application communicate to it and delegates the execution of business rules (or other application business logic probably) to this component. 
There are many ways of communication to this component. In general there are two approaches, (1) compiled code references or (2) service based interactions.
If you are in the same technology stack that the component is written, you can simply reference that component and use it. To know how exactly you should do is to refer to the user manual of the component. If you like to have a service based interaction, then, you simply need to know the service interface. For instance if the service provides a REST API then you can use a [JavaScript client](http://www.flexrule.com/archives/javascript-decision-as-a-service/) from your PHP application to interact with the business rule service.